# Using SQL to compare counts of identifiers from two tables

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, correlated-subquery

I'm trying to construct a query that compares two tables with identical structure

```
Table 1:
ID | Data 

Table 2:
ID | Data
```

ID is a nonunique key (Data is repeatable but ID|Data combos are unique). I need a list of IDs where the  COUNT of those IDs is greater in Table 2 than in Table 1.

So for example, if

```
Table 1
a | data
a | data1    
b | data2

Table 2
a | data
a | data1
b | data2
b | data3
```

would generate the output "b"

This feels like it should be easy, but my head is scrambled right now. I'm doing this in mysql if that affects options.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To get the count for each key,

```
select count(*) as count, ID from Table1 group by ID
```

So, use this as a sub-query in the from clause, and join the tables.

```
select tt1.ID
from (select count(*) as count, ID from Table1 group by ID) tt1
  inner join (select count(*) as count, ID from Table2 group by ID) tt2
     on tt1.ID = tt2.ID
where tt1.count < tt2.count
```

Comment: Does mysql allow a select query where you're not selecting anything?

Answer (score 0):

Tested in MySQL.

```
select case when count(d1.id) > count(d2.id) then d1.id end as 'id'  from 
(select id from t1) d1,
(select id from t2) d2
group by d1.id
```

Comment: I like this solution as well since I hadn't use select case in MySQL before. But this place only lets me pick one right answer and the other seemed generalizable to more situations.